# Custom option values depending on the screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The below is currently being used in my page.

```
<script id="score" type="text/template">
    <select name="scoreSelector">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Your Score</option>
        <option value="0.25">Quarter</option>
        <option value="0.50">Half</option>
        <option value="0.75">Three Quarter</option>
    </select>
</script>
```

How can I set the value of each option depending on the screen width?

Example

```
var width = $(window).width();
if (width <= 1023) {
    //set <option value="0.25">Quarter</option>
} else {
    //set <option value="0.35">Quarter</option>
}
```

Comment: This is an odd requirement. Depending on your need it would seem to be a much better solution (not to mention simpler) to always keep the values in the select the same, but instead do the calculation of the required output based on the window width when an option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You may do :

```
var width = $(window).width();
if (width <= 1023) {
    $('select[name=scoreSelector]').val('0.25');
} else {
    // etc.
}
```